# Import large excel file without changing datetime in Matlab

Tags: matlab, datetime, import

I want to process a monthly excel file but when using readtable, it changes the time column from HH:mm to 0.001 etc. How can I import it without changing its format?

```
data = readtable('Book1.xls')
d = strcat(table2array((data(:,1))), {' '}, table2array((data(:,2 ))));
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it self-contained, nobody should have to download an ominously ambiguous `Book1` from an external site, especially as `.xls` files can contain macros...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use `readtable` to do this. Then you can convert it correctly.

Something like [this](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/499599-how-to-import-correct-time-format-from-excel).

```
table= readtable('Book1.xls');

Col2 = datetime(table.Time, 'ConvertFrom','excel', 'Format','HH:mm');
DT = table.Date+timeofday(Col2);%adding column 1 and 2 of the data
```

Then `Col2` should have the correct values, `DT`should have both Col1 And Col2 values.

Comment: I believe you can add them up, I've changed the code for it.

Comment: You'd need to probably have a function that substitutes that as in [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/741222-replace-nan-with-blank-in-a-table). I do not have the time for a couple of days to check this fully and add to the code, but I'll test when I can to see if it works.